# Plugin for coloring and displaying line numbers of code snippets inserted into CodeSnippet plugin

Tags: ckeditor

Is there any good plugin for code snippet presentation. I am using CodeSnippet plugin in the CKEditor, and I would like to nicely present that within my web, adding coloring for specific languages, number lines, etc

Answer (score 0):

[Prism](http://ckeditor.com/addon/prism) is a good plugin that do the syntax highlighting for code snippets